# Test Pre-Compile function on directive

Tags: angularjs

How do I unit test a precompile function on a directive? I can just check the scope post compile but was wondering if there was a better way.

```
angular.module('app')                                                        
  .directive('mailcheck', function () {                                                        
    return {
      compile: function() {
        return {                                                                               
          pre: function(scope, element, attributes, controller) {                              
            scope.mailcheck = controller;                                                      
          }
          post: ...
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

Test:

```
'use strict';

describe('Directive: mailcheck', function () {                                                 

  // load the directive's module
  beforeEach(module('8SecondsToTradeGuiApp'));                                                 

  var element,
    scope;

  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope) {                                                    
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    element = '<input mailcheck>';                                                             
    element = $compile(element)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
  }));    
});
```